# Not scrolling screen

Tags: android, scroll

I have layout the file of the screen in which there is GridView with elements and lianerlayout is slightly lower in which shall information on clicking elements in GridView is output. Here XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="360dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/calendar_top" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/previous"
                android:layout_width="40dip"
                android:layout_height="30dip"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/arrow_left" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_calendar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/next"
                android:layout_width="40dip"
                android:layout_height="30dip"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/arrow_right" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:numColumns="7"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
        </GridView>

    </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linLayout_all_ivents_in_this_day"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

            </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The screen is scrolled if I expose any value of height, in my case 360dp (android:layout_height = "360dp"), but it looks ugly and if I expose android:layout_height value = to "wrap_content", it looks as it would be desirable that, but the screen ceases to be scrolled.

Answer (score 1):

You should try adding a ScrollView as the parent view and your XML code in that view. Keep android:layout_height = "wrap_content". Also use "match_parent" instead of "fill_parent". Try this code:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/calendar_top" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/previous"
            android:layout_width="40dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/arrow_left" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_calendar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="40dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/arrow_right" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:numColumns="7"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
    </GridView>

</LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linLayout_all_ivents_in_this_day"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

If you wish to make your GridView scrollable you can do the same by adding it inside another ScrollView

Comment: Didn't work, the screen everything also isn't scrolled

Comment: I am sorry I think I have not understood your question clearly then. The scrollView will make your entire layout scrollable and the GridView is already a vertically scrolling widget.